# How to keep certain factors while changing others with the ifelse() function in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I am very new to programming in R and I am still learning a lot, so my question might sound a bit foolish for the more advanced programmers of you.
At the moment I have problems with the `ifelse()` function in R.

My column (lets call it A) I have problems with looks like this:

```
irelevant
irelevant
2
6
very important
5
very important
irelevant
4
```

Because of that I wanted to use a `ifelse` function to turn the "very important" into a 7, the "irelevant" into a 1 and keep the other factors. So I tried this;

```
Data$B <- ifelse(Data$A == "irelevant", 1,
                        ifelse(Data$A == "very important", 7, Data$A))
```

Unfortunately it didn´t work and strangely it returned my column like this:

```
1
1
3
7
7
6
7
1
5
```

The function converted "irelevant" and "very important" correctly but added +1 to all other factors. How can I avoid that or improve my function? I would be really glad if you could help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert everything to `character` before running `ifelse`:

```
gg = c("irelevant", "irelevant", 2, 6, "very important", 5,
       "very important", "irelevant", 4)
gg = as.data.frame(gg)
gg$gg = as.character(gg$gg)
gg$bb = ifelse(gg$gg == "irelevant", 1,
               ifelse(gg$gg == "very important", 7, gg$gg))
gg

> gg
              gg bb
1      irelevant  1
2      irelevant  1
3              2  2
4              6  6
5 very important  7
6              5  5
7 very important  7
8      irelevant  1
9              4  4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The "gg$gg = as.character(gg$gg)" part was my mistake. Now it works fine. Have nice day.

Comment: You too. Happy to help :)